# Add Overlay to Bootstrap full screen fixed image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a full screen fixed image and I would like to add an overlay over top but nothing I've tried has worked.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="overlay">
        <img src="image.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>

.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
.container>.overlay>img {
    position: fixed;
}
.container>.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    z-index: 3;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/extyehqz/

However this produces nothing

Comment: Can you create a demo?

Comment: Remove position:fixed and try

Comment: Added fiddle. I tried removing fixed position but that didn't change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best idea to go with this would be making the image the background image of the body. Here is a solution following this idea. If you really want it to be an image element let me know I will post a solution on that.
The main idea is to use

```
background-color: rgba(...);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j1quLk7h/

Comment: Edit: Changes the fiddle since the first link was wrong check again

Comment: Also For future reference here is how you would do it for single images that are not in the background https://jsfiddle.net/afsf7nev/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question. That can be an approach.

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
.container>img {
    
}
.container>.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    z-index: 3;
    position: fixed;
    opacity:0.4;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="overlay">
      
    </div>
  
    <img src="http://goo.gl/2Xzi3L" />
    
  
</div>
```